# GoogleSignIn with Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

In my Android application to use Google Login with firebase I read the docs, but the function "firebaseAuthWithGoogle" not exist.

My project Grandle file dependecies

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

//Facebook
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.32.0'
```

And activity result function is

```
protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN_GOOGLE) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // ...
        }
    }
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I cannot find solution. Whats is wrong?